# Suppose $f^2=0$ implies $f=0$. Does this mean that $f^2(m)=0$ implies $f(m)=0$ for every $0\neq m\in M$?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, bimodules

Let $R$ be a ring with unity, $M$ be a right $R$-module and $\text{End}_R(M)$ be the endomorphism ring of $M$.   Suppose that $\text{End}_R(M)$ is a reduced ring, that is, $f^2=0$ implies $f=0$ for every $\text{End}_R(M)$.

**Question:** Is it right to conclude that for any $0\neq m\in M,$ $f^2(m)=0$ implies $f(m)=0$?

My thinking is that it is right since $f^2(m)=0$ for $m\neq 0$ implies $f^2=0$.  Since $f=0$ by hypothesis, $f(m)=0$.

Comment: You seem to be misplacing quantifiers here. $f^2=0\implies f=0$ means $(\forall m\neq 0, f^2(m)=0)\implies (\forall m\neq 0, f(m)=0)$, not $\forall m\neq 0, (f^2(m)=0\implies f(m)=0)$.

Comment: In principle, you might have and $x$ and $y$ such that $f^2(x)=0$ and $f^2(y)\neq 0$, in which case the condition that $f^2=0$ would not be applicable.  That is, unless you insist upon the proper quantification, as in the comment above.

Comment: @Maxence1402 Why $m \neq 0$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I simply reused what mariam wrote.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments